# Build and use tensorflow with sse2

Tags: tensorflow

I installed tensorflow using pip3 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 and when running my script it says

> Using TensorFlow backend. 2018-12-03 09:26:03.005585: F
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow
>   library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't
>   available on your machine. Aborted (core dumped)

cat /proc/cpuinfo gives me:

> processor       : 0 vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD cpu family      :
>   16 model           : 5 model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 635
>   Processor stepping        : 2 microcode       : 0x10000db cpu MHz
>   : 800.000 cache size      : 512 KB physical id     : 0 siblings
>   : 4 core id         : 0 cpu cores       : 4 apicid          : 0
>   initial apicid  : 0 fpu             : yes fpu_exception   : yes cpuid
>   level     : 5 wp              : yes flags           : fpu vme de pse
>   tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx
>   fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext
>   3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid pni
>   monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm
>   sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt hw_pstate vmmcall
>   npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save bugs            : tlb_mmatch fxsave_leak
>   sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2 bogomips        :
>   5800.53 TLB size        : 1024 4K pages clflush size    : 64 cache_alignment : 64 address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits
>   virtual power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate

I have been trying to build tensorflow from sources using bazel, but that gives me

> ERROR: /home/xxx/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:256:1: every rule of
>   type proto_library implicitly depends upon the target
>   '@com_google_protobuf//:protoc', but this target could not be found
>   because of: no such package '@com_google_protobuf//': The native
>   http_archive rule is deprecated.
>   load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
>   for a drop-in replacement. Use
>   --incompatible_remove_native_http_archive=false to temporarily continue using the native rule. ERROR: Analysis of target
>   '//tensorflow/core:example_java_proto' failed; build aborted: Analysis
>   failed INFO: Elapsed time: 244.392s INFO: 0 processes. FAILED: Build
>   did NOT complete successfully (467 packages loaded, 9450 targets
>   configured) FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (467 packages
>   loaded, 9450 targets configured)
>       Fetching @aws; fetching 30s
>       Fetching @boringssl; fetching 20s
>       Fetching @org_sqlite; fetching 4s
>       Fetching @com_google_protobuf; fetching

Does someone has an advice for me?

Comment: What version of Bazel are you using? For TensorFlow v1.12 I had to use Bazel 0.18.1, since Bazel 0.19 would not work due to deprecated Bazel directives in TensorFlow (so I image later version would not work either).

Answer (score 0):

I finally built tensorflow successfully to work with my CPU using bazel build param

> --copt=-march=native